# First query to SOLR takes 30 times longer than the following queries

Tags: php, solr

I'm using Solr PHP extension. The code looks something like this:

```
$client =  new SolrClient($instance);
$response1 = $client->query($query1);
$response2 = $client->query($query2);
```

First query takes about 160ms. Second (third, forth...) query takes about 5ms. Queries are different so it's not cache. And it's not the specifics of the queries since switching places for queries makes `$query2` to be very slow and `$query1` fast.

Obviously it's not about the query, but about connecting to SOLR for the first time. And it's not about network lag since the second query is very fast. Any ideas on what it is and how to speed it up?

Comment: DNS lookup the first time? How do you access your Solr server?

Comment: Are they against the same field? Do they use the same sort? Do they contain the same filters in `fq`? Are the index files stored on a rotating disk? Are they in the io cache for the first request?

Comment: SOLR is on localhost on a certain port.

Comment: @MatsLindh queries are completely different. It's not about queries. I just tried pinging SOLR client `$client->ping();` before running any queries. And now ping takes about 160 ms and both queries take 5ms.

Comment: Attach a debugger to the JVM to see where the delay is, and use strace or something similar on the client to see if the delay is on that side.

Comment: @jeroen You were right. The delay is caused by the resolving of the SOLR host. Even when it's localhost it still takes 160ms.

Comment: That's long. Is it set correctly in the hosts file? You could also try 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Resolving SOLR host caused the delay. Even when it was localhost or domain listed in /etc/hosts it still took much time. Changing domain to IP made all queries run in under 5ms.

Interesting detail. When using file_get_contents resolving was under 1ms. But when using CURL or SOLR client it took 160ms. We still haven't figured out this issue, but it's a different story.